# Javascript inside r chunk of code (rMarkdown document)

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown

Is it possible to send value from javascript function to r variable? Something like this one:

````
<script>
function myFunction(){
return('Hello World!')
}
</script>

```{r}
variable = myFunction()
print(variable)
```
````

Thank you very much for your advice in advance.

Comment: RBloggers made a nice article about that topic: https://www.r-bloggers.com/new-in-v8-calling-r-from-javascript-from-r-from-javascript/